# Codeigniter - Is it possible to redefine anchor function

Tags: codeigniter, anchor, redefinition, urlhelper

I have human friendly urls without index.php. I had to modify .htaccess file for that. Actually I always use Codeigniter like this. My url-s always look like this:

```
www.example.com/controller/function/parameter
```

So if I have an extra url parameter, then the url looks like this:

```
www.example.com/controller/function/parameter?archive=2013
```

**Now what I want to do: If there is 'archive' parameter in the url, than also add that to the url when anchor function creates a link.**

We have some different stuff every year (like stylesheets), so I need to make this navigation automatic. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is "Yes".

I slightly modified the solution from here:

[How to extend anchor() function to anchor_admin() in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296593/how-to-extend-anchor-function-to-anchor-admin-in-codeigniter)